# read latin1_swedish_ci text in MySQL using MyBatis

Tags: mysql, encoding, mybatis

I am using Mybatis to connect to a MySQL database, some columns are using latin1_swedish_ci as character encoding, that result weird texts when interrogating the database.

I tried to change the encoding on the java code but no solution works for me.

What I tried:

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(myString)
```

or:

```
byte ptext[] = myString.getBytes("latin1");
String value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
```

any solution to get the data on the UTF8 encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, to anyone that have this problem,
In my case, the characters should be in arabic, I managed this by:

- In the configuration file, I changed the connection string to this

  jdbc:mysql://path.to.db?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
- Whenever I need the text on the readable format, I use this

  String readableString = new String(dbString.getBytes("8859_1"), "Cp1256");

Answer (score 0):

Connect using utf8, not latin1.  MySQL will convert as it reads from the latin1 columns.